# join two xml and count

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. Anyone know how to group two xml and count the number of order for each customer? Really confused how to group it and how to write the select part.

first xml

```
<Seq1>
  <Customer CustomerID="g">G</Customer>
  <Customer CustomerID="p">P</Customer>
</Seq1>
```

second xml

```
<Seq2>
  <Order OrderID="41" CID="p">card</Order>
</Seq2>
```

and what I want to get

```
<GroupJoin>
  <Join>
    <Customer CustomerID="g">G</Customer>
    <Group Count="0" />
  </Join>
  <Join>
    <Customer CustomerID="p">P</Customer>
    <Group Count="1">
      <Order OrderID="41" CID="p">card</Order>
    </Group>
  </Join>
</GroupJoin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is complete solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input1 =
                "<Seq1>" +
                  "<Customer CustomerID=\"g\">G</Customer>" +
                  "<Customer CustomerID=\"p\">P</Customer>" +
                  "<Customer CustomerID=\"r\">R</Customer>" +
                  "<Customer CustomerID=\"s\">S</Customer>" +
                "</Seq1>";

            XElement element1 = XElement.Parse(input1);

            string input2 = 
                "<Seq2>" +
                  "<Order OrderID=\"11\" CID=\"r\">flash</Order>" +
                  "<Order OrderID=\"12\" CID=\"r\">mouse</Order>" +
                  "<Order OrderID=\"21\" CID=\"s\">phone</Order>" +
                  "<Order OrderID=\"22\" CID=\"s\">pc</Order>" +
                  "<Order OrderID=\"23\" CID=\"s\">camera</Order>" +
                  "<Order OrderID=\"41\" CID=\"p\">card</Order>" +
                "</Seq2>";

            XElement element2 = XElement.Parse(input2);


            var results =
                (from cust in element1.DescendantsAndSelf("Seq1").Elements("Customer")
                join order in element2.DescendantsAndSelf("Seq2").Elements("Order") on cust.Attribute("CustomerID").Value equals order.Attribute("CID").Value into comb
                from noMatch in comb.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { Customer = cust, Order = noMatch == null ? null : noMatch })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Customer.Attribute("CustomerID").Value, y => y)
                .ToList();
            //<GroupJoin>
            //  <Join>
            //    <Customer CustomerID="g">G</Customer>
            //    <Group Count="0" />
            //  </Join>
            //  <Join>
            //    <Customer CustomerID="p">P</Customer>
            //    <Group Count="1">
            //      <Order OrderID="41" CID="p">card</Order>
            //    </Group>
            //  </Join>
            //  <Join>
            //    <Customer CustomerID="r">R</Customer>
            //    <Group Count="2">
            //      <Order OrderID="11" CID="r">flash</Order>
            //      <Order OrderID="12" CID="r">mouse</Order>
            //    </Group>
            //  </Join>
            //  <Join>
            //    <Customer CustomerID="s">S</Customer>
            //    <Group Count="3">
            //      <Order OrderID="21" CID="s">phone</Order>
            //      <Order OrderID="22" CID="s">pc</Order>
            //      <Order OrderID="23" CID="s">camera</Order>
            //    </Group>
            //  </Join>
            //</GroupJoin>
            XElement groupJoin = new XElement("GroupJoin");
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                XElement join = new XElement("Join");
                groupJoin.Add(join);
                join.Add(result.FirstOrDefault().Customer);
                XElement group = new XElement("Group");
                join.Add(group);
                if (result.FirstOrDefault().Order != null)
                {
                    var count = result.Count();
                    group.Add(new XAttribute("Count", count));
                    foreach (var order in result)
                    {
                        group.Add(order.Order);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    group.Add(new XAttribute("Count",0));
                }
            }


        }

    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> groups = [Seq2].GroupBy(cid => cid.Value);

Dictionary<string, List<string>> result = groups.Select(customerId = groups[customerId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the descendants of the nodes based on customer id and group them together to get the results. The following query should to the trick:

```
var customers = XElement.Parse(@"<Seq1>
  <Customer CustomerID=""g"">G</Customer>
  <Customer CustomerID=""p"">P</Customer>
  <Customer CustomerID=""r"">R</Customer>
  <Customer CustomerID=""s"">S</Customer>
</Seq1>");

var orders = XElement.Parse(@"<Seq2>
  <Order OrderID=""11"" CID=""r"">flash</Order>
  <Order OrderID=""12"" CID=""r"">mouse</Order>
  <Order OrderID=""21"" CID=""s"">phone</Order>
  <Order OrderID=""22"" CID=""s"">pc</Order>
  <Order OrderID=""23"" CID=""s"">camera</Order>
  <Order OrderID=""41"" CID=""p"">card</Order>
</Seq2>");

var results = customers.Descendants("Customer").Join(orders.Descendants("Order"),
        c => c.Attribute("CustomerID").Value,
        o => o.Attribute("CID").Value,
        (c, o) => new{ Customer = c, Order = o})
    .GroupBy(x => x.Customer)
    .Select(g=>
    {
        var customerOrders = g.Select(x=>x.Order).ToArray();
        var customer = g.Key;
        var @group = customerOrders.Any()? new XElement    ("Group",customerOrders):new XElement("Group");
        @group.SetAttributeValue("Count", customerOrders.Length);
        return new XElement("Join",new[]{customer, @group});
    });
new XElement("GroupJoin", results).Dump();
```

Here is the output in LinqPad:

[image: Query results.]

Comment: You missed the null items in the join.  See my solution.